# Time displayed is different from my system time

Tags: android, logging, time

I have logged the time taken to post and get a reponse from a server. But the time seems to be 4 hours ahead of my system clock.

The code I used is :

```
String posttime = java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
Log.i("Time at which HTTP POST was sent",""+posttime );
```

The output in the log is :

> Time at which HTTP POST was sent(323): 8:24:53 PM instead of 4:24:54PM.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The time is in `UTC`, you need to change the `TimeZone` to your local timezone

for example:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();       
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: @tyczj..Thanks for the reply. I tried America/New_York to get EST, but it does not seem be working.